# Load PHP link into IFrame

Tags: php, asp.net

I created one aspx page with one iFrame and upload on windows server. Also I have another PHP site which is upload on PHP server.

Now when I passed the PHP URL into IFrame but it is not load. When I change the URL to `www.google.com` then its load. When I passed the PHP URL then its not display into iFrame.

```
<iframe src="My PHP URL"></iframe>
```

Comment: Are you sure you put the right PHP URL?

Comment: what is your url. ??? i think the problem is with the URL ..